# Refresh the page with new request on change select option

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to achieve something via php.

Here there are couple of options.

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
  <option selected="">Select Clusters ...</option>
  <option value="math-related">Math Related</option>
  <option value="science-related">Science Related</option>
</select>
```

There are Group of subject fields which will appear when the options are changed respectively.

```
<div class="form-row pb-5" id="math-related"">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num1" placeholder="English">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num2" placeholder="Math">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num3" placeholder="Science">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num4" placeholder="Computer">
      </div>
</div>
```

When the option is changed to **Math related** OR **Science Related** option, the related 5-6 subject fields will be populated like image below. Some might have 5, some might have 8.

How to refresh the page and load the new sets of input fields according to selection done via PHP?

[Example Image for fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61ivO.png)

Comment: I'd suggest not reloading the page, but rather use Ajax/javascript to change the values. This way none of the form data will be lost.

Comment: @aynber I understand your point, but isn't it possible to save the data and reload the page also loading new sets of the field according to selected option through PHP?

Comment: You could, as long as you make sure to save the data. But you'll also need javascript to reload the page `onChange()`.

Comment: @aynber save data like options selected?

Comment: Anything that might be in the form that would have already been entered.

Comment: @HungerFeel Why would you prefer to reload the page when you could just use Ajax to load in the data in the already loaded page?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am new to Ajax, I don't have any experience in it. I thought it can be done via PHP.

Comment: @HungerFeel It's simply JavaScript. It's not really possible with just PHP/HTML. PHP is a server side language, once it's done running, it's done. It can't do anything else. And HTML doesn't really _do_ anything in general. This is where JavaScript steps in, and allows you to do things on the client even after the PHP is done running.

Comment: @aynber it is in WordPress can you help, please? I might need to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your select dropdown with your page url + parameter and make sure to replace YOUR_PAGE_URL with actual url as follows -

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
  <option value="">Select Clusters ...</option>
  <option value="YOUR_PAGE_URL?topic=math-related">Math Related</option>
  <option value="YOUR_PAGE_URL?topic=science-related">Science Related</option>
</select>
```

After then just do a GET parameter checking on your page to populate your fields like -

```
if( issset($_GET['topic']) ){
    if( $_GET['topic'] == 'math-related' ){
        echo "Add your math related above 5-8 fields html here.";
    }elseif( $_GET['topic'] == 'science-related' ){
        echo "Add your science related above 5-8 fields html here.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am nearly there, only Problem is that option selected gets back to default (select clusters...). It should be the same as selected in previous before the page is reloaded. For example, once the science related is selected after the page is reloaded with get parameters. The selected option should be science related.

Comment: Just add selected attributes for selected GET parameter value and replace your dropdown option like  - <option value="YOUR_PAGE_URL?topic=science-related" <?php echo(isset($_GET['topic']) && $_GET['topic'] === 'science-related' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Science Related</option>. Do the same for rest options values.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks :)